# "To die being hit" vs "to die from being hit."

Tags: expressions

What the difference between the two? Which is more commonly used by native speakers of English?

Example:

> It’d be tragic, don’t you think? To die (from) being hit by an apple.”

Comment: The difference is that *from* attributes cause of death to being hit by the apple. Without it you're just describing the process and letting any listeners draw their own conclusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above, "from" indicates causation.

If you want to convey the message that the person died from being hit by the apple you would need "from."  If he just happened to have a heart attack or something at the same time the apple hit him, you could leave "from" out.

Comment: Omitting *from* means the sense defaults to inserting *while*.

Answer (score 0):

"To die being hit"

indicates simultaneity: the person dies practically at the time with receiving the hit.

Similar to:
"To die **while** being hit"
"To die **while** hit"

There's no such temporal implication in the other, which is all causality.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I like your answer, but I was a little confused by your last sentence. I think it might be clearer if you explicitly stated "the other" as "to die from being hit". My personal preference is to include as much detail as possible because the questions and other answers often change over time as the community improves them.